# Is there a way to store npm .tar files in a remote repository in Artifactory?

Tags: npm, artifactory

Currently when I cache npm packages in a remote repository in Artifactory it seems to save a package.json file which contains a link to the external registry where the .tar file can be downloaded.

Is there a way to configure the remote repository to save the actual .tar files themselves, so that packages can be downloaded from Artifactory and not from external repositories?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the external dependencies installed using the post-install script, you will need to use [this optio](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-AutomaticallyRewritingExternalDependencies)n to download the dependencies through Artifactory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have my virtual repository configured to enable dependency rewrites, and I've specified my remote npm repository for cache, however when I run npm install it still only caches the package.json files and not the .tgz packages. 

Is there a way to configure it to cache the .tgz packages as well?